# Why SSH Windows is able to connect some IP's and not connecting some IP's?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, ssh

I'm using Windows (10) SSH(Putty) to connect ubuntu servers. I have a list of servers. 
In that, I'm able to connect a few servers and few are not connecting via the same SSH.

[image]

But I can connect those in different ubuntu(console SSH) system.

How to allow all IPs to connect in Windows system ?

Comment: The `ssh` command is not PuTTY; it's OpenSSH.

Comment: Are the working servers and non-working servers on the same network? Do you have root access to one of the non-working servers (to run a packet capture)?

Comment: Can you create a Virtualbox VM with an Ubuntu client on that Windows 10 machine? Make sure the network is set to "bridged", then try again from that VM.

Comment: Run the command like this for more information: `ssh -v root@server`